# Which Nobel prize winners names besides Townes were used as code names for Fujitsu computers?

Tags: history

Fujitsu named its late 80s/90s personal computer FM Towns after physics Nobel prize winner [Charles Townes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_H._Townes). According to the sources ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FM_Towns), [2](https://web.archive.org/web/20101121042646/http://www.old-computers.com/museum/computer.asp?st=1&c=968)) I could find, using Nobel prize winners as code names was typical at Fujitsu during that time.

Which other Nobel prize winners did Fujitsu pay tribute to by code naming their computer products after them?

Comment: Not from Fujitsu, but there is another Nobel prize named computer: the Tatung Einstein (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tatung_Einstein)